# How did Bajoran light ships get into space?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I don't recall there ever being any mention of these craft having rocket or ion propulsion or anything of the like, how did they overcome Bajor's gravity (the grav-plate Sisko added himself and the zero-g toilet suggests they had yet to simulate gravity themselves)?

Comment: Most likely they were constructed in space, from parts launched from Bajor and materials found on Bajor's moons or nearby asteroids.  There are light ship designs that can go SSTO, but they require gigawatt ground-based laser arrays to launch anything interesting.

Comment: Like most everything on Bajor, it works by magic! Or the Prophets, whatever.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there are any details in DS9 or any other Star Trek material (I've checked Memory Alpha, Memory Beta, and Ex Astris Scientia).

I would say the answer is: how do we get anything into space right now? Stick it on a liquid fuelled rocket and point it up.

Comment: I would have gone with *... and light the candle* but *... point it up* gets the message across just as well.